# c# winforms: change label text with right click by calling previously specified methods

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, mouseevent, right-click

I am very new to programming, and I am playing around with Windows Forms.

I have a form with one label and two buttons, clicking on spremeniButton changes the text in the label, and clicking on the povrniButton changes it back. What I want to do now is set up a MouseUp event, in a way that whenever a right click is performed on the label, the same set of events happen as with the clicking on the buttons.

I have set up the button_click methods for both buttons, but now I am having problems with calling the methods from within the label1_MouseUp method. I don't know if I should use an if statement or something else, but I don't want to write a separate piece of code to achieve the same solution, I just want to use the already written methods.

If someone can point me in a right direction I will be very grateful. Thanks.

```
private void spremeniButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    label1.Text = "Nov napis";
    spremeniButton.Enabled = false;
    povrniButton.Enabled = true;
}
private void povrniButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    label1.Text = "Originalni napis";
    povrniButton.Enabled = false;
    spremeniButton.Enabled = true;
}
private void label1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
    if ((e as MouseEventArgs).Button == MouseButtons.Right)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void label1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

        if ((e as MouseEventArgs).Button == MouseButtons.Right){
            if(povrniButton.Enabled){
                povrniButton_Click(sender, null);
            } else {
                spremeniButton_Click(sender, null);    
            }
        }
}
```

You can actually call the button functions inside your event. Given that  you disable the button once clicked, i've used that to check which event to call when the user performs a right click.